# Допустим что длина списка изменяемая, и применение - range(3) неактуально. Как правильно искать значение в списках списка в таком случае?

Tags: list, циклы, поиск

Допустим нужно найти в списке число 3 и 4, но список изменяемый и количество элементов в нем меняется. Как правильно заменить в этом примере range(3) на универсальный способ перебора.

```
board = [[1,[2]],[1,[2]],[[3],[2]],[1,[4]]]

def MakeListOfFreeFields(board):
    free = []   # the list is empty initially
    for row in range(3): # iterate through rows
        for col in range(3): # iterate through columns
            if board[row][col] not in ['O','X']: # is the cell free?
                free.append((row,col)) # yes, it is - append new tuple to the list
```

Comment: Поместите код согласно правилам, пожалуйста. Он же нечитаем.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то ваша проблема состоит в том, чтобы определить длину массива. Это поможет сделать функция `len(board)`
Далее пройтись циклом `for` по массиву я думаю не составит труда